# Python: Failing to break out of while loop with "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop"

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I am developing a breadth-first-search algorithm for a factorization problem and am running into an interesting/confusing bug when attempting to break out of a while loop. If you run the code below, it will fail inside the "construct_path" method, stating :

File "main.py", line 96
    break
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop

but I am inside of a while loop! If anyone could give me some advice on this issue, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
from numpy import random
import itertools
import Queue




#Finding multiples, BFS problem
#Given input of list with unique integers 0 - 9 and n = range(0,1000000), calculate smallest multiple of n and unique combination of values in the list

#Example : Input : list = {0,1,2} , n = 3, 
#           output = 12
#          Input : list = {0,1,2} , n = 50
#          Output = 200

class Problem:



    def __init__(self):
        self.n = random.randint(0,10000000)
        listSize = random.randint(1,9)
        mainSet = set()
        self.mainList = []

        while True:
            toAdd = random.randint(0,9)

            if(toAdd not in self.mainList):
                self.mainList.append(toAdd)

            if(len(self.mainList) == listSize):
                break




    def get_start_state(self):
        s = ''.join(map(str, self.mainList))

        return int(s)

    def is_goal(self, state):
        return True

    def get_sucessors(self):
        print "Getting successors"



def breadth_first_search(problem):

    # a FIFO open_set
    open_set = Queue.Queue()
    # an empty set to maintain visited nodes
    closed_set = set()

    # a dictionary to maintain meta information (used for path formation)
    meta = dict()  # key -> (parent state, action to reach child)

    # initialize
    start = problem.get_start_state()
    meta[start] = (None, None)
    open_set.put(start)

    while not open_set.empty():

        parent_state = open_set.get()
        print "{} {}".format("parent_state is ", parent_state)


        if problem.is_goal(parent_state):
            return construct_path(parent_state, meta)

        for (child_state, action) in problem.get_successors(parent_state):
            if child_state in closed_set:
                continue

            if child_state not in open_set:
                meta[child_state] = (parent_state, action)
                open_set.put(child_state)
        closed_set.add(parent_state)

#collect path to desired answer
def construct_path(state, meta):
    action_list = list()

    while True:
        row = meta[state]
        if (len(row) == 2):
            state = row[0]
            action = row[1]
            action_list.append(action)

        else:
            break


    return action_list.reverse()


x = Problem() 

breadth_first_search(x)
```

Comment: Which is line 96, and did you really need to post all the rest of that code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce a syntax error from the code you have posted.

Comment: I just ran this code and it works perfectly fine for me. The `break` statement does its job. So, could you provide us with a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Be a little imaginative, guys!  How could that lower `break` be outside of a loop?  Taken as a riddle, the question provided enough information to take an educated guess and provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you have a mix of tabs and spaces so that the `break` in line 96 looks like it is indented to be below `action_list.append(action)` but effectively it is below the `while`.  That would explain the error at least.

It is just a guess.  But it could be like this, using a visible tabwidth of 4 in the editor:

```
→   while True:
→   →   row = meta[state]
        if (len(row) == 2):
            state = row[0]
            action = row[1]
            action_list.append(action)

        else:
            break
```

To the Python interpreter this looks like this (because it assumes a tabwidth of 8):

```
→       while True:
→       →       row = meta[state]
        if (len(row) == 2):
            state = row[0]
            action = row[1]
            action_list.append(action)

        else:
            break
```

This is still valid but obviously means a different thing and would put your break outside of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. My editor was not showing any tab-related issues, but after removing and replacing all tabs, it worked. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  "Thank you" comments are not needed (but I appreciate it of course); if an answer is useful for you, you should upvote it (upwards triangle next to the answer).  If it solves your issue, you should accept it (check mark next to the answer).